# How to get $\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta p}\right)_T$ from $\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta p}\right)_V$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

How to get $\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta p}\right)_T$ from $\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta p}\right)_V$ ?
I was trying to find $\left(\frac{\delta T}{\delta p}\right)_H$, and found that is $$-\frac{T\left(\frac{\delta p}{\delta T}\right)_V + V\left(\frac{\delta p}{\delta V}\right)_T}{T\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta T}\right)_p\left(\frac{\delta p}{\delta V}\right)_T }$$

But I cannot use $\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta p}\right)_T$, I can use $\left(\frac{\delta p}{\delta V}\right)_T, \left(\frac{\delta p}{\delta T}\right)_V, S,\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta V}\right)_p$

How can I do this?

Comment: _Thermodynamics_ by Callen has a chapter on Maxwell relations in which he explains how one derives such equations in a mechanical fashion. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

$S$ can either be a function of $p,T$ or $p,V$ (since $p,T,V$ are related by an equation of state). So we can relate the derivatives by the chain rule
$$S(p,V)=S(p,V(p,T))$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right)_V+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_p\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T$$
So if you know everything on the right hand side you have the answer. $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T$ isn't on your list of quantities you can use, but you can use $$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_T=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T}.$$